# Padding bytes were not empty : while decoding txn input data

Tags: transactions, abi, raw-transaction

I'm decoding the raw input data of an eth transaction. I have the function signature to decode the input with.

I'm using the `eth_abi` library for python.

```
res = eth_abi.decode(['address', 'address'], eth_utils.decode_hex(input))
```

`eth_utils.decode_hex()` converts hex to bytes.

this throws:

```
Padding bytes were not empty: b'\x1c\xffy\xcd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Some examples:

```
paramList= ['address', 'bool']
input= "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000b25cd920f3cb29e9de2a1f55577a3fe539d187a70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000159b4fa00"
```

```
paramList= ['uint256']
input= "0x2e1a7d4d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000214e8348c4f0000"
```

Can anyone help me out??

Comment: looks like some thing wrong with the input, can you give the sample `input` value that cause the error ?

Comment: I've added some examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You must skip the 4-byte function signature in your input data before calling `eth_abi.decode`
2. You used the wrong paramList in one of your example.

To decode it, you can use:

```py
eth_abi.decode(paramList, eth_utils.decode_hex(input)[4:])
```

The first example you gave should be decoded as `transfer(address,uint256)` because the second argument is not "bool" encoded, [See the function signature here](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0xa9059cbb)

```py
paramList = ['address', 'uint256']
input= "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000b25cd920f3cb29e9de2a1f55577a3fe539d187a70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000159b4fa00"
eth_abi.decode(paramList, eth_utils.decode_hex(input)[4:])
```

Output: `('0xb25cd920f3cb29e9de2a1f55577a3fe539d187a7', 5800000000)`

The second example is ok to be decoded using the above:

```py
eth_abi.decode(['uint256'], eth_utils.decode_hex("0x2e1a7d4d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000214e8348c4f0000")[4:])
```

Output : `150000000000000000`

Read more on ABI encoding and why paramList is wrong and you should skip the first 4-byte: [Solidity Documentation on ABI encoding](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html#examples)

Answer (score 0):

'padding bytes were not empty' means the hex value you are passing has more than one value in it.

log out the `input` you are feeding `eth_utils.decode_hex()`, and slice the signature (or other value) from the front of the hex literal. Append `0x` to the front of the resulting hex, if necessary, and try again.